# BSOD after update windows 10 on Acer Switch 10 E SW3-013-N12P/W

Tags: windows, bsod, windows-10, tablet

After I update the newest release (today) is 'Cumulative Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3081424)' my tablet become crazy. First it got BSOD with the error code 0xC000021A then it automatically reset the system. Repeat many times, sometimes it's allow me to access to windows but can't do anything because the modern UI was crash, that it open fixing windows or something, I'm not sure. So I completely reset the Windows 10, delete everything.

Do you know what is the result? Another BSOD, and this time is much more worse, this BSOD don't have code name except this name 'inaccessible_boot_device'! Now what! What am I supported to do?!

[Update] I don't know if this info useful or not, but I think I should share all I know, that windows was updated while my tablet was charging. Is it ok?

More info about my tablet:
• Name: Acer Switch 10 E
• Code: SW3-013-N12P/W (http://www.acer.co.jp/ac/ja/JP/content/model/NT.MX1SJ.001)
• OS: Windows 10 - 32bit
• The original language is Japanese because I bought it from Japan. However I've changed it to English before upgrade to Win10.

Some docs that I have referenced:
support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/156669
answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/inaccessible-boot-device/446dfdf5-17a2-4505-9d1f-5415a0c3bc5f
reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3f01mi/windows_10_inaccessible_boot_device_after_reset

I've ask on Windows 10 support forum but no-one help me so I hope somebody in here could help:
answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/bsod-after-update-windows-10-looking-for-the/1d662007-f143-428c-84be-737bf1485e3e?tm=1438929002268

Answer (score 0):

I updated my desktop last night with this update and my desktop got a BSOD as well. I reverted it back to my previous restore point before the update installed and it hasn't had a problem since.

Comment: I didn't make a backup yet so...